# remove leading zero from numbers without decimal in R vector

Tags: r

Say I have a vector `myvec <- c("00890","0891","Apple-20","00-china-usa","0123Belgium")`. 
I want to remove all the zeros before numeric values in this vector and not from alpha-numeric and get the result as shown below.

result

```
"890", "891", "Apple-20","00-china-usa","0123Belgium"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with gsub and regular expressions. Putting the `[1-9]` in brackets allows you to select it to remain in the output using the `\\1`

```
gsub("^0+([1-9])","\\1",myvec)
```

edit: actually, that cuts the 0 from 0123Belgium, this works:

```
ifelse(grepl("[A-z]",myvec),myvec,gsub("^0+([1-9])","\\1",myvec))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this with `sub`.  We match strings that start (`^`) with one or more zeros followed by one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) that we capture as a group (i.e. inside the `(..)`) until the end (`$`) of the string.  In the replacement, we use the backreference (`\\1`) to replace with the captured group.  Note that this will not touch the leading 0's in strings that have character suffix. i.e. `0123Belgium` in this example.

```
sub("^0+([0-9]+)$", "\\1", myvec) 
#[1] "890"          "891"          "Apple-20"     "00-china-usa" "0123Belgium"
```

Or use the `^` to match only numeric elements and not any alphabets.

```
sub("^0+([^[:alpha:]]+)$", "\\1", myvec)
```

Testing with another `vector` to check whether this answer fails or not

```
sub("^0+([0-9]+)$", "\\1", myvec1) 
#[1] "8090"                "10"                  "00-china-012Belgium" "012C001"
```

#### data

```
myvec <- c("00890","0891","Apple-20","00-china-usa","0123Belgium")
myvec1 <- c("008090", "010", "00-china-012Belgium", "012C001")
```

Comment: Thanks, it does. I thought that comment was directed towards me.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative , we can convert the elements in `myvec` to numeric and the one which are alphanumeric are kept unchanged.

```
ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(myvec)), myvec, as.numeric(myvec))

#[1] "890"          "891"          "Apple-20"     "00-china-usa" "0123Belgium" 
#Warning messages:
#1: In ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(myvec)), myvec, as.numeric(myvec)) :
#NAs introduced by coercion
#2: In ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(myvec)), myvec, as.numeric(myvec)) :
#NAs introduced by coercion
```